# Script to reload or refresh Div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two divs side by side, one say DIV 1, has a textarea, which when I type into it automatically updates the database on every keyup...

The second one DIV 2 has a Google Maps. So if I type a place into DIV 1, a live search is made and the final result is entered into some temporary table in my database (in the background). When I'm done typing, I want to click on some button in DIV 1, which then reloads DIV 2, with the Google Map. The Google Map code takes the values from the temporary values table and displays them.

For now I can do all of the above except that. What I want to do is not to reload the whole page: I just want to click on a button in DIV 1, and reload DIV 2 to show the new marked locations that I have searched for.

I just want to reload DIV 2 using a button in DIV 1.

The two DIVs are below:

```
<body onload="load()">
  <div id="div1">
    <input id="searchfield" autocomplete="off" />
    <input type="button" id="send"/>
  </div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: You can use [iframe](http://google.com/search?q=iframe), [Ajax](http://google.com/search?q=ajax) or [Websocket](http://google.com/search?q=websocket).

Comment: well than please please edit a bit more your question, sounds interesting but I think your thoughts are mixed, and your question unclear, cause you actually don't type into a DIV but into an `<input>` field. etc...

Comment: @roxon, yess, i type into an input.. 
    <input id="searchfield" autocomplete="off" />
 this code

Comment: what code exactly? please don't be so mysterious **☻** What you want to accomplish? Please explain exactly

Comment: what i intend to do is to refresh div2 using the button in div1, a googlemaps map is displayed in div2, but the marked locations that it shows are values from a table in my database, theses values change depending on what the user searches for ...
so if the user searches from a particular type of place, this means the places like that must be shown on the map in div2, and for these places to be shown, the user has to reload the whole page.. isnt it better to just reload div2 which has the map instead of the whole page. so i intend to use a button in div1 which when clicked, it will reload div2

Comment: a while later after some reading and intense practise, i came back to this post and felt very embarrassed!!! haha... Well, it was a learning curve for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating a database on *"every key up"* is a suggestion I would never give to anyone, especially to an amateur programmer.

Update some states on the page live without refresh? On submit? O.K! Great idea, then use [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

Ok, you know that Google Maps (V3) uses 2500 calls-per-day and you want to leverage that calls maximally, you should recall your updated data via AJAX into your canvas element and redo the Markers positioning. Again AJAX.